# Highstock line chart xAxis datetime being sampled down

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I have a highstock line chart displaying daily and weekly stock prices for a given stock. Problem is when the data array is large enough the daily data points get "sampled" into weekly data points and weekly data points get sampled down to monthly data points.

Is there a way to prevent this?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting the dataGrouping enabled as false

```
// other settings here
plotOptions : {
    area : { // change this to the chart type you use
        dataGrouping : {
            enabled: false
        }
    }
}
// other settings here
```